# Getting all directives that defined at module

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS will create [name]Directive service for each directive when you define them.

Are there any ways that I can get the set of directives that I have created in a specific module?

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('aa',...)
.directive('bb',...)
.directive('cc',['allDirectiveService',function(allDirectiveService){
// can access all the directive here
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your position I would declare a submodule of my main app module only for Directives, something like that:

```
if (window.myApp == null) {
  window.myApp = {
    myApp: angular.module('myApp', [ 'Directives']),
    Directives: angular.module('Directives', []),
  };
}

myApp.Directives.directive('myDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false
    };
  }
]);
```

And then I suppose that if you do something like `console.log(myApp.Directives);` you can see all your Directives. I havent tested it but I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although I am not on a system I can verify the variable name.
There is an array that contains all registered directives, services, etc. You can iterate through the list and pull out the directives.

```
// Variable starts with underscore and is an array
angular.module('foo')._
```